# Get Media entity field values in custom validation handler

Tags: 8, media

I am trying to put a custom validation on node form which has paragraph attached to it. The problem is I am not getting paragraph field values available in form_state of my validation handler.

I just see the delta of entites when I do a debug on form_state

[image]

As in the screenshot field_asset the entity_reference_revision referencing a [media entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity), I only see two entities attached in form_state in custom submit handler on node_form but how can I get value of those refernced entities?

Update: I realised it was not paragraph entity but media entity.

Comment: $node->field_asset->getValue() have you tried this. Have you tried to get value method ??. I am assuming your field to be a entity reference field with multiple values .

Comment: node is not created yet during form validation as it could be form edit/create.

Comment: are you performing validation on node_content_type_edit_form ??

Comment: $form_state->getValue('field_asset'); Have you tried this . Is your validation called ??

Comment: The debug output is from validation so that is sure it is getting called, the getValue will return the value as shown in the output, however, paragraph is set of different fields, I am looking a way to get hold of nested values.

Comment: "paragraph is set of different fields" would you mind explaining this ?? I assume it to be a field collection

Comment: @ShreyaShetty paragraph is just like field collection with only difference lies in the type of widget it provides, with paragraph you can attach different paragraph entity bundles while field collection allows single type of field collection bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging the form_state I found the user submitted values for embedded media entites lies at form state storage. My validation code now looks like

```
/**
 * Implememts hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodulename_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal \Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $operative_form = array(
    'my_node_add_form',
    'my_node_edit_form'
  );
  if (!in_array($form_id, $operative_form)) {
    return;
  }
  $form['#validate'][] = '_mymodulename_validate_element_node_form';
}

/**
 * Custom validation handler for EDP.
 */
function _mymodulename_validate_element_node_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form_storage = $form_state->getStorage();
  $form_storage_embed_entities = $form_storage['inline_entity_form'];
  foreach ($form_storage_embed_entities as $key => $value) {
    $media_entities = $value['entities'];
    foreach ($media_entities as $media_entity) {
      if ($media_entity['entity'] instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface) {
        if ($media_entity['entity']->getEntityTypeId() == 'media') {
          $asset_type[$media_entity['entity']->field_asset_type->value] = $media_entity['entity']->field_asset_type->value;
        }
      }
      if (count($asset_type) > 1) {
        // early bail.
        break;
      }
    }
    // Validation condition goes here.
    if ($validation_condition) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('field_asset', t('Did you try turning it on and off.'));
    }
  }
}
```